# Dynamically sized table in the cell of another table not resizing when reshowing view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView of cells where one cell contains a UITableView. Selecting that row that contains the table pushes a new view onto the screen with a list of items. The user selects a list of items and then presses 'back' to pop that view. The parent view looks at the number of items selected and the height of the cell is supposed to adjust to show all items selected.

What happens is that when the view is reshown, the listed items extends into the cell below. If I scroll that cell off the screen, then back to it, the cell is then the right height showing all items correctly.

I've tried several things such as putting code into viewWillAppear of the main table like [self.view setNeedsDisplay] and [self.view setNeedsLayout], but it doesn't work.

I can't seem to find a way to make that cell redraw to it's right size without scrolling the table once the view appears.

Is there some other method to force the redraw before it actually appears?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
NSIndexPath *theIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellRow inSection:cellSection];
NSArray *theIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath];
[table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:theIndexPaths withRowAnimation:NO];
```

What are you currently using to redraw the cell?  Just waiting for it to redraw itself when it goes off screen and back on?  Or are you using something like [table reloadData];?

Comment: On the main tables viewWillAppear I am calling reloadData at the point. Which goes through and calls things like heightForRowAtIndexPath which is where I determine how many selected items there are for me to display and return the adjusted height for row with the table.

Comment: BTW, where are you recommending I place your code that is suggested?

Comment: If you are calling reloadData then I would think it would reload that cell anyway.  I just tested in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear and it works for me in both places.  Just make sure the data for your height is correct before those functions are called.